# D3.js Map visualization like marker clustering of leaflet

Tags: d3.js, dictionary, leaflet, data-visualization

I am developing map with many markers on it. I use the as my first start [here](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html) . It has world map and handle maker cluster but Now we need only US map no other data needed and also need to functionality on zoom behavior for state,County,neighborhood etc while zoom in go step by step .

I am wondering if I d3.js with US map and topojson data is there any example available for cluster maker on map with d3.js ?

Or leaflet example with zooming function modification also welcome
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by cluster marker?

Comment: while we zoom out it will collapse closer markers in big one and show numbers of grouped markers in it